# Scope Access Performance in CFM vs. CFC

Tags: coldfusion

I understand that this question might be slightly academic, but I am just attempting to understand this behavior in ColdFusion.

When accessing the REQUEST scope on a CFM, it takes less time than accessing the REQUEST scope in a method. The only difference, as far as I can tell, when looking at my .class files is that, inside a method, it has to reference the CFPage argument to access the structKeyExists() method to check the REQUEST scope. In addition, another oddball, is that accessing the THIS scope is faster than accessing the VARIABLES scope in a method in a CFC.

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

index.cfm

```
<cfscript>

tests = new tests();

request.test = {
    "foo":[1]
};

iterations = 10000;

starttime = getTickCount();
for( i=1; i<=iterations; i++){
    if( structKeyExists( request, "test" ) ){
        request.test.foo[1];
    }
}
writeoutput( "REQUEST scope access on CFM: " & getTickCount()-starttime & "<br>" );
tests.test( iterations ) ;
</cfscript>
```

Test.cfc

```
component{

function test( iterations ) {
    // test variables
    variables.testvar = {foo : [1]};
    this.testvar = {foo : [1]};

    var startTime = getTickCount();
    for( var i=1; i<=iterations; i++){
        if( structKeyExists( request, "test" ) ){
            request.test.foo[1];
        }
    }
    writeOutput( "REQUEST scope access in method: " & getTickCount()-startTime & "<br>" );

    startTime = getTickCount();
    for( i=1; i<=iterations; i++ ){
        if( structKeyExists( variables, "testvar" ) ){
            variables.testvar.foo[1];
        }
    }
    writeOutput( "VARIABLES scope access in method: " & getTickCount()-startTime & "<br>" );

    startTime = getTickCount();
    for( i=1; i<=iterations; i++){
        if(structKeyExists(this, "testvar" ) ){
            this.testvar.foo[1];
        }
    }
    writeOutput( "THIS scope access in method: " & getTickCount()-startTime & "<br>" );


}
```

---

Just a fun aside -- isNull() is faster than structKeyExists() when the key exists. However, structKeyExists() is faster when the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't mean to be obtuse (honestly, I don't) but what's the actual question. Is it just along the lines of "why?"

Comment: Hah, you are being very kind Adam. I was expecting more fervor! Yes, it's just a "why?" I understand if these types of questions annoy some people, but it is more of curiosity thing. I've been working on the answer myself. I added the "why" to my question.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate an answer to this question!

Comment: Also, something fun -- isNull() is faster than structKeyExists() when the variable exists, but slower when the variable doesn't exist! I added this to my comment.

Comment: Accessing the request scope (or other similar scope, such as form, url, session, etc.) directly inside a CFC method breaks encapsulation. I would try passing the request scope to the test() method and see if that increases performance.

Comment: Yes, Scott, it definitely does! However, that did not prevent developers from putting it in there. In addition, the THIS vs. VARIABLES performance is confusing.

Comment: With very few exceptions - such as creating DTOs for passing data to client as JSON - I never use the THIS scope.

Comment: Agree, VARIABLES is where it's at! But why is it slower than THIS access?

Comment: Don't know...and, honestly...don't care :D

Comment: I modified the code so that request scope is passed into test() as an argument and referenced as an argument and the speed in that method is much better, and is usually faster than accessing request scope in the .cfm file. https://gist.github.com/boyzoid/c35923d7cf4185517f5e

Comment: At that point, a copy of the pointer to request would be put into the local scope, which should make it the same speed as accessing local/arguments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57527/discussion-between-j-t-and-scott-stroz).

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your "why?" but a different "why?".

Why do you care? In a real-world sort of way, I mean. Enough to ask on StackOverflow.

I think it's a great question (and the sort of stuff that fascinates me), but I blog about this sort of thing, and it's my hobby.

However from a work-a-day point of view, before I started concerning myself with any of this sort of stuff, I'd be assessing *how big* the performance difference is? If, for argument's sake, you needed to loop over your code 1000000 times to amplify it enough to see meaningful results that using the request scope was twice as slow (at 2000ms, say) than using a passed-in reference (1000ms), it's not the 100% difference that's important; it's the fact that the difference is only 0.001ms per iteration: ie, it simply doesn't matter.

I make a point of posting this answer not necessarily for you, but for people who come later: be cautious of micro- / premature-optimisation. This sort of thing will be very unlikely to be the cause of anything you actually need to optimise.

In the meantime... have you run your tests on Railo to see if there's any differences?

It'd be cool if you could blog all your findings!

Comment: Adam, I love your blog and read old posts frequently just to keep the information fresh. However, I don't think I would be good at maintaining my own blog. My current project has me tuning a fairly complex high-volume process which has already been tuned with respect to all the standard stuff short of a complete rewrite. After this pass we are going to Java, which is going to be expensive. So, I'm basically after every microsecond at this point. I totally agree that under most circumstances, even for us, these optimizations are probably the last to consider. This is an exceptional situation.

Comment: Fair enough. This sounds like one of those rare situations which this *isn't* premature optimisation. If you wanted to write something up about it, feel free to flick it through and I'll publish on my blog under your name. It'd be interesting stuff for the community. Obviously fair enough if it's not something you're interested in though!

Comment: At the same time, it is fascinating stuff just to get a baseline for how long CF takes just to do stuff. For instance, the fact that the Java JIT compiler will take nice clean native JAVA classes with lots of small functions and put them inline into one giant function to keep the code faster is a huge loss for us since the compiler only gets every method as a class architecture with CFML. So, writing "clean" code with lots of small functions can be a disadvantage in ColdFusion for CERTAIN high volume actions. Really just cool to learn.